# What are the correct Springboot -Kafka parameters in application.yml?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

Trying out a hands on with Springboot-Kafka. A couple of doubts. Are these valid parameters for Kafka tuning in `application.yml`:

```
fetch-max-bytes: 52428800
```

Any idea if this is a valid property on Kakfa? I am using it in `application.yml` in my springboot project to control my consumer polling behaviour. Secondly, in this block are there multiple threads launched internally by the `KafkaListener`:

```
@KafkaListener(id = "instance1", groupId = "${spring.kafka.consumer.group-id}", topics = "${spring.kafka.consumer.topic}")
    public void consume(String message) {
        System.out.println("Hellolistener ..."+message);
        log.info("container1 Message recieved from Kafka topic :{} ", message);
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without a prefix, those are just regular user-properties that you would need to wire in yourself via `@Value`

You can find all `spring.kafka` properties [in the Spring documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/application-properties.html)

That being said, the two properties you listed are not listed there, but that doesn't prevent you from creating your own ConsumerFactory where those properties could get added

Comment: you are right! but max-poll-interval-ms is a valid kafka property and i removed it from question. but i now realize so is fetch-max-bytes:

Comment: Indeed, `fetch.max.bytes` exists in `ConsumerConfig`, but you'd have to ask the Spring developers why that wasn't added

Comment: You can always set arbitrary consumer properties from `spring.kafka.consumer.properties.` prefix, though

Answer (score 2):

If you are using `org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka`, please see the following images, it does not have mentioned properties.

[image: prop1]

[image: prop2]

On your other question, for concurrent kafka listeners I created a `@Bean` of `ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory` and pass it as an argument to the parameter `containerFactory` in `@KafkaListener` annotation.